# Delphi XE5 Android. Hardware back button press

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, back-button, delphi-xe5

How simulate hardware back button press to close application?

I need close the application by code but Application.Terminate, Close, Hide and DisposeOf do not work.

So I thought to simulate hardware back button press to achieve my goal.

Comment: Do you need to simulate anything? Isn't it enough to close your app?

Comment: There is currently a glitch in Application.Terminate. Try this: `try
formandroid.Hide;

Application.MainForm.DisposeOf;

except

on e:exception do
begin
Application.MainForm.DisposeOf;
end;
end;
end;`

Comment: @mg30rg he also wrote "close application" which I took to be goal

Comment: Sorry, I - somehow - did not notice.

Comment: Application.Terminate, Close, Hide and DisposeOf doesn't work.

Comment: @trexios, edit your question and add what you have tried.

Comment: Found a similar thread on embarcadero suggesting to try halt; https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93120&tstart=0... on a side note, it's interesting to see that a simple thing such as closing the application gets to be so tricky... doesn't sound like delphi, imho.

Comment: Seems to me that you should understand why you cannot close your application rather than flailing around attempting to fake back button press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    MainActivity.finish;
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make your application handle when users press the Back button on their Android device, add an event handler to your form for OnKeyUp, and use the following code within your event handler:

```
if Key = vkHardwareBack then
begin
// Do whatever you want to do here
Key := 0; // Set Key = 0 if you want to prevent the default action
end;
```

Comment: The probleme with trapping vkHardwareBack  is that you can no longer close de virtual keyboard.